# Rule based symbology after clip in Qgis

Tags: qgis, symbology, clip

I tried clipping Vector layer by Vector-Geoprocessing tools-Clip but when I clip it seems that Rule based symbology of the Vector layer is not kept.

Is there a way to clip and to keep rule based symbology of the "original" layer automatically without copying the style manually afterwards?

Comment: i meant automatic

Answer (score 1):

You can use the "**edit features inplace**" function for some processing tools. It is available for "clip" processing tool. Enable the function and then start the algorithm:

[image]

Note that it works a bit differently from the "normal" processing tool:

1. Select the layer you wish to clip in the layers panel
2. Choose "edit features inplace"
3. Start the "clip" algorithm
4. As layer you can now only choose the overlay layer
5. Run it
6. Changes will not be saved automatically, so if the result is fine for you, disable the edit mode of the layer to save the changes
7. Deselect all features and you will see that your symbology is still there

---

Another method is to **copy paste** the symbology:

1. Right click the original layer
2. Choose "Styles" -> "Copy Style" -> "All Styles"
3. Right click the new layer and paste it the same way

[image]